# Algorithm Analysis -- Big O Notation

Tags: c, big-o

What's a good strategy to determine the running time (Big O notation) of data structures and algorithms. I have the following to figure out the running times for and I'm having 
trouble determining what it would be.

AINC is an array containing n integers arranged in increasing order.

AD is an array containing n integers arranged in decreasing order.

AR is an array containing n integers in random order.

Q is a queue implemented as a linked list and containing p elements.

LINK is a linked list containing n nodes.

CIRC is a circular linked list containing n elements, where C points to the last element.

T is a binary search tree containing n nodes.

a) Searching for an element in AINC using linear search.

b) Deleting the 10thnode of linked list LINK.

c) Calling a function which uses Q, and calls dequeue m times.

d) Inserting an element at the end of the list CIRC.

e) Deleting the last element of CIRC.

f) Finding the largest element of T.

g) Determining the height of T.

h) Making the call selectionsort (AINC, n).

i) Making two calls one after another. The first call is mergesort(AD,n), followed by the call insertionsort(AD,n).

j) Converting a decimal integer *num* into its binary equivalent.

***This is not hw. I am preparing for an exam.

Comment: Please tell me this is homework?

Comment: nope im studying for an exam.

Comment: @Krysten big difference indeed

Comment: Is that your homework?, If yes u have to do it yourself, If No then share your answers and lets discuss them.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ

This is bad. You should feel bad.

Comment: I am very much tempted to provide an answer with my standard DIY-strategy on this. Think the OP would want that?

Comment: This is not hw everyone.

Comment: @thkala that would be very much appreciated

Comment: ok, share the answers please.

Comment: Alright if I were to take a gander, I would say: a -- O(n) because you have to a linear search.. b -- O(1) because there is only one operation. c -- O(m) because the running time is dependent on how many times m is called. d -- O(n) e -- O(n) f -- (logn) g -- O(logn) h -- O(n) i --- (n^2) j -- O(n)

Comment: If you're preparing for an exam, you must have some kind of material to study or have been taught some kind of strategy for dealing with the problem of determining runtime complexity. I can't imagine that you're unable to solve a single one of these problems if you've  actually studied! Read your material and ask a more specific question if you run into problems. Would be glad to help, but currently that would mean repeating all the lectures in this course for you :)

Comment: I am studying for a CS foundation exam that covers material from a class I took last semester.  I don't have sufficient notes for this topic. I am not asking for answers, but a strategy/method to make figuring this out easier.

Comment: C may depend a bit on what the function is doing to the queue as some operations may not be constant time if the list is singularly linked as deletions may require a traversal to reset what the next removal node should be, just something to point out.

Comment: b) it is right O(1) but it is not one operation, you trace the pointers in the first nine element then  delete the 10th element, and change the pointer in the 9th element, it is O(1) because the number of operations is constant.

Comment: d) I think it is O(1) not O(n)

Comment: g) and I think is O(n), u must try all the routes, in the worst case the height will be 'n' when it is like linked list

Comment: h) selection sort always has a time complexity of 'n^2'

i) merge sort --> O(n.lgn)
   insertion sort -->O(n) in this case, as it will find the current element always less than the first one

j) is a function of x, where x = number of digits in 'num'

Comment: @omar I thought insertion sort was always O(n^2).

Comment: @Krysten: yes it is, but in that case u only have to make one comparison for each element, as the element at the top of the "sorted" list, always is larger than the next element, so only one comparison is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since the OP asked for it)

You pick up a piece of paper.

- If your question mentions a number (e.g. repeat *n* times, or find the *n*-th last element):

You perform by hand on paper the operations needed to perform the mentioned action when that number is 1 (if applicable).

You repeat for each of the following values of that number: 2, 10, 20, 100, 1000 and 10000. Just for kicks you can also try with the actual number mentioned in the question.

You measure the time it took you for each case and then you plot on a piece of paper (oh, a spreadsheed would also do, I suppose) the function `t(n)`, where `t` is the time, and `n` the number.

You look through your old math books to identify the curve. E.g. if it's a parabol, you most probably have an O(n^2) algorithm in your hands.

- If your question does not mention a number:

Repeat the previous procedure above by using 2, 10, 20, 100, 1000 and 10000 elements in any data structure mentioned (array, list etc). If the "structure" is a number, just use that many digits.

NOTE:

If you manage to visualise the procedure above *without* turning half of this planet's remaining trees into paper or having your hand fall off, then you are half-way towards a semi-decent intuitive technique.

You should read up on the proper mathematical way to deal with this, though - intuition can only take you so far in this case.

Additionally, most of the examples that you mentioned are so basic that most people just memorize (and a bit later they just *know*) their complexities. You should really get a book or some decent notes on this. [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/) is a nice, big fat *introductory* book on this field.

EDIT:

Searching for `algorithms and complexity` in Google also produces a whole pile of interesting results. You should try it once in a while...

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Big O analysis and have some time (2.5 hours), I would recommend watching the first two [lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) of this algorithms class delivered by Leiserson himself.